# Reusing A UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to have a static grouped uitableview that on each cell the user clicks it will take him to another uiviewcontroller there he will need to give information through various tools xcode provides.
heres an example:

First cell will take him to a vc there user will input name, mid name and last name.

Second cell will allow user to select date and time.
Third cell will allow user to input address, 
and so on, I will have about 6-8 cells

Is the only answer for this is having a lot of viewcontrollers@storyboard/nib files? 
Or that there is some way this all can be done using 1 viewcontroller that will change depending on the cell you choose?
I'm asking since I want to take performance under consideration and make the app more dynamic.

Comment: The time it takes to load up a new xib would be offset by the time it takes to set a bunch of .hidden properties. Having one view with a lot of UIControls to keep track of will just be a pain once you start getting 6-8 views worth of input forms to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same Xib's and can make the change the text of label as per your requirement.
Once, you are selecting a cell, depending on selection of cell you can pass an integer and in viewDidLoad of second controller you can hide the not required UI elements.

If you are using StoryBoard you can use like :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]){
      StoryDetails *controller = (StoryDetails *)segue.destinationViewController;
      controller.dataModel= storyModel;         //pass the data here

}
```

In case of Xib's :

```
YourViewController *controller=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerName" bundle:nil];
 controller.dataModel= storyModel;         //pass the data here
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd prefer to separate out all the different viewControllers by function. If you go the route that uses tags to programatically hide the UIControls you do/don't need for this function, you're going to have a lot of code smell. As you add more functions the xib and .h/.m will just get more convoluted.

```
//tableViewDidSelectRow...
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    ViewControllerName *nameView = ...
    //display this view...
} else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    ViewControllerDate *dateView = ...
    //display this view...
} else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    ViewControllerAddress *addressView = ...
    //etc etc etc
}
```